# Complex ASP.NET MVC5 EF6 Linq query

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework

I am converting an old classic asp **(YUCK!!)** application to a ASP.NET MVC5 Web Application.
One report in particular is an aggregation, that previously was created by building a dynamic sql query and executing it in a loop.

I would like to convert the entire thing to a linq query, but am struggling with doing the pivot.

Essentially, in my app, there are numerous Entities (businesses) who fill out a set of questions from a category and question set, with the number of questions being dynamic for each category.

**Question Structure:**
QuestionSet has Categories has Questions (each their own table).
Entities answer questions with a response and evaluation (in an answers table).

The old report I am trying to rebuild ***shows a list of entities and their answers to each question for a specific category*** and is shown here:
[image http://workitonline.biz/temp/aggregation-practice_classic.png](http://workitonline.biz/temp/aggregation-practice_classic.png).

The old code is like this **(I have omitted a lot for breivty's sake):**

```
'Get all the questions with filters
Dim rsQuestions : Set rsQuestions = objAuditAggregation.GetQuestionsFiltered(p_categoryId, p_questionGroupId, p_priority)

' Dynamically construct the query based on how many
' question are in the category
Dim questionValues : questionValues = ""
Dim questionTables : quesitonTables = ""

Dim totalQuestions : totalQuestions = 0

While(Not rsQuestions.EOF)  
    i = rsQuestions.Fields.Item("id").Value

    questionValues = questionValues & 
    questionTables = questionTables & 

    totalQuestions = totalQuestions + 1
    rsQuestions.MoveNext                            
Wend

'Get all the entities and their answers (filters omitted)
Set rsEntities_cmd = Server.CreateObject ("ADODB.Command")
rsEntities_cmd.ActiveConnection = MM_raworkit2004_STRING
rsEntities_cmd.CommandText = 
    "SELECT DISTINCT E.EntityId, EntityName, 
    ISNULL(EA.include, 1) AS include", a" & i & ".yourEvaluation AS yourEvaluation" & i & ", a" & i & ".yourResponse AS yourResponse" & i 
    FROM tbl0101Entity E 
    INNER JOIN tbl0102User U ON U.EntityId = E.EntityId 
    LEFT JOIN tbl12EntityAggregates EA ON E.EntityId = EA.entityId 
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT entityId, yourEvaluation, yourResponse 
           FROM tbl12Audit 
           WHERE questionId = " & i & " AND entityLevelAudit = 1) AS a" & i & " ON E.EntityId = a" & i & ".entityId"

Set rsEntities = rsEntities_cmd.Execute
```

**So, to the .NET Code.** I have the following view models to display the data:

```
public class AggregationPracticeConductViewModel : BaseModel
{
    public ICollection<EntitiesAndAnswersViewModel> EntitiesAndAnswers { get; set; }
    public AggregationPracticeConductFiltersViewModel Filters { get; set; }
    public bool Display { get; set; }
    public bool Updated { get; set; }
    public bool IsAdmin { get; set; }
}

public class EntitiesAndAnswersViewModel : BaseModel
{
    public Entity Entity { get; set; }
    public bool Include { get; set; }
    public ICollection<AnswersViewModel> Answers { get; set; }
}
public class AnswersViewModel
{
    public int QuestionId { get; set; }
    public int? Evaluation { get; set; }
    public int? Response { get; set; }
}
```

And I have the following controller code to fill the view models.

```
private ICollection<EntitiesAndAnswersViewModel> getEntitiesAndQuestions(AggregationPracticeConductViewModel apdvm, AggregationPracticeConductFiltersViewModel filters)
    {
        var query = from e in _repository.GetAll<Entity>()
                    from u in e.Users                        
                    where (e.AuditQuestionGroupId != null ? e.AuditQuestionGroupId : 0) == this.LoggedInEntity.AuditQuestionGroupId
                    select new { entity = e, user = u };

        var query2 = from a in query
                     join ea in _repository.GetAll<EntityAggregate>() on a.entity.EntityId equals ea.EntityId into eas
                     from ea in eas.DefaultIfEmpty()
                     group a.entity by new { entity = a.entity, ea = ea } into newGroup
                     orderby newGroup.Key.entity.Name
                     select new EntitiesAndAnswersViewModel()
                     {
                         Entity = newGroup.Key.entity,                            
                         Include = newGroup.Key.ea == null ? true : newGroup.Key.ea.include   // If there are no entity aggregate record yet, return as include = true                                                   
                     };                                     

         // TODO: Now join the entities with their results. This is what I have so far
        var results = from e in query2
                      join a in _repository.GetAll<ReviewAnswer>().DefaultIfEmpty() on e.Entity.EntityId equals a.entityId
                      where a.Question.Category.QuestionGroup.Id == (e.Entity.AuditQuestionGroupId != null ? e.Entity.AuditQuestionGroupId : 0)
                      && a.Question.Category.id == filters.SelectedCategoryId && a.entityLevelAudit == true
                      group e by new { e, a } into group1                          
                      select new EntitiesAndAnswersViewModel()
                      {
                          Include = group1.Key.e.Include,
                          Entity = group1.Key.e.Entity,
                          Answers =  // list of AnswersViewModels e.g. new AnswersViewModel { QuestionId = answer.question, Evaluation = answer.Evaluation, Response = answer.Response}
                      };
        return results.ToList();
    }
```

Obviously the code is not working as in the last query I don't know how I could group by the entity and the set of questions, and then return a list of answers inside the Select statement. But up until the TODO:, the code is getting exactly what I want.

It's just this last query that I am no even sure if it's possible to do in linq.
Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: So, are you telling us that the YUCKy code works and the good code doesn't?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately :-(

Comment: Unfortunately you've cut enough out of the original that it doesn't seem to relate.  Simply though... no easy variable-column queries via LINQ.  You could fill a `DataTable` from the appropriate SQL maybe?